# Flutter & Android: Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.2 and Gradle 7.0.2

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I got this on my android part of Flutter.

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.2 and Gradle 7.0.2.

Possible solution:
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project
```

Please kindly tell the solution to this. I would really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Change Gradle version to 7.3

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Gradle 7.0.2 support java version 16, in your project Java is setted for version 17, so solution is to upgrade gradle version or downgrade Java version.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, in gradle-wrapper.properties you can change distribution URL from 7.0.x to 7.4.1

Answer (score 75):

Every answer they give different java version or different gradle version.

To avoid this confusion, I listed Java/Gradle compatibility table.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

> **Example**: If your gradle version 7.5, you should set java version 18 or below.

[image]

**How to change Java version?**

> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build tools -> gradle ->
> Gradle jdk -> choose Java version based on your gradle version.

Comment: This helped me `Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build tools -> gradle -> Gradle jdk -> choose Java version based on your gradle version`

Comment: Incredibly helpful. Thank you. I wish there was a more seamless way to do this like just pick up whatever version is being used in `jenv` or something. It's confusing to  be able to switch `jenv` versions but still run into these conflicts

Answer (score 59):

After Updating Android studio I have faced this issue.

You Can Simply Follow These steps:

Open Your Android Studio Project

Go To **Gradle Scripts** -> **gradle-wrapper.properties**

My old setting like this

[image: My old setting like this]

Now You Can Change distributions/Gradle versions **7.2 To 7.6** [image: 7.2 To 7.6]  like this

it's working for me .

You can also use 7.4 + version . it's also working for me.

Comment: I wasn't prepared to upgrade Gradle version for a very legacy project. This did the trick.

Comment: Does this affect android version compatibility. Like it won't work on certain devices or something? @Ronik Limbani

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html 
you can check official docs for this

Answer (score 22):

Go to file > project structure > SDK location > Gradle settings
There choose Embedded jdk.
This will resolve the issue.

Comment: In some cases, it can be more efficient to consider downgrading the Java version, particularly when dealing with an older codebase. This approach can help avoid complications that might arise when upgrading the Gradle version, which could subsequently necessitate updates to various libraries, potentially leading to compatibility issues and a cascade of errors.

Answer (score 11):

You can resolve this by changing the Gradle version on `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and the JDK version from the project structure.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

**Steps**

- Navigate to the root of your project. In my own case *-/flutterProject/*
- Locate and goto *gradle/wrappper*   folder, Where you will find *gradle-wrapper.properties* file.
- there you will change the distributionUrl to the new version

  Ex: *distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip*

Answer (score 3):

Gradle 7.5 not supports java version 19, so the solution is to upgrade gradle version or downgrade Java version.

in my case I'm upgrade the gradle version as showing below

1. [Click on setting at right side end and click on "Project Structure"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiCv1.png)

2. [Change the Gradle version to 7.6 and then click and apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdhKb.png)

3. [Goto Build option and click on "clean" project and "rebuild project"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd1ay.png)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the latest version of the Android Studio(Pelican). To fix the problem I modified this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

And in the build.gradle(ANDROID):

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2' //THIS VERSION WORKS!!!
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java/Gradle versions compatibility matrix can be found here:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

It can be seen that Java 17 is not compatible with Gradle 7.0. In case you want to keep the Gradle version, you can downgrade Java to version 16 by the next steps in Android Studio:

- File
- Project Structure...
- SDK Location
- Gradle Settings
- Gradle JDK
- Download JDK...
- Set version to 16 and click Download

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Java version to Java 11 and try again.
it works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35304652)

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla how is this not an answer?

Comment: Provide some explanation as to why Java 11 works and other options don't.